# Has an order with this property a special name?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, order-theory

If $a$ is an element in a preorder then you can eventually go 'a step back' (and repeat this) in the sense of finding an element with $b\leq a$ and not $a\leq b$.

> Is there a special name for (pre)orders in which for every element such a route back can only contain a *finite* number of steps?

This question occurred when I was looking at factorization in irreducibles in an integral domain.

Comment: This sounds like a well (pre-)ordering.

Comment: Is the [descending chain condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition) good enough?

Comment: @GitGud Well. I kind of disliked 'dcc' and was looking for something like: there are factorizations in irreducibles if the order induced by ... is 'a well(pre)order' (or something else)...

Comment: @Hurkyl Has the term well-preorder some official status? Or did you just created it yourself?

Comment: Whoops, I meant well-founded, not well-ordered. Wikipedia applies the term well-founded to *any* relation, not just to orderings, although the definition is modified slightly for preorderings: a preorder is well-founded if $<$ is well-founded as a relation.